Astronaut turns into a monster
When I was a child, I saw a movie that was about an astronaut who returned from a space mission with a virus or something in him that turned him into a monster at the end.  In the movie, he is stopped by a child and there is tension whether he would do something bad to her but instead he just moved on (this is 1950-who knows what would happen now?).  At the very end he winds up on the top of a skyscraper and I think he was like a giant octopus.  And of course he is killed.  Like most science fiction this was warning us of space travel.  And like older movies, it sounds really cheesy, I guess, but as a kid, it scared me.  I never saw it again, unlike most of the other science fiction movies.  Does any one know the name of it?

This sounds like The Quatermass Xperiment (AKA The Creeping Unknown) from 1955:

Professor Bernard Quatermass is in charge of a manned rocket mission that has gone awry. They lost contact with the spaceship at one point and have no idea how far into space it may have traveled. When the rocket crash lands in a farmer's field they find that only one of the three occupants, Victor Carroon, is on board; the others have simply vanished. Slowly, the surviving astronaut begins to transform into a hideous creature and Quatermass realizes that Carroon may have been infected by an alien being. When Carroon escapes from the hospital with the help of his unsuspecting wife, the authorities race to destroy it before it multiplies.

The astronaut runs across a child, but she survives. In the end, he fully turns into a tentacled monster (that looks like this) and climbs Westminster Abbey. Here's the original trailer:




I can see where Species II got its core plot from.
